# Tokenize a string with delim of strings

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi

If I have a string like

> "This is a string that will be split by this and that"

I would like to get the split results as

1. "is a string that will be split by"
2. "and that"
3. "this is a string"
4. "will be split by this and"

1 and 2 are split by "this"
3 and 4 are split by "that"

My solution is use a map of string to string and store the result in another map of the same type-string to string. However, for more complex and longer text, the results stored in the map become repeated, i.e as in the above 1 and 3 the substring "is a string" is repeated and this redundancy produces incorrect statistical results.

Would you please offer a neat better solution to tokenizing a long string with delimiters that are different long strings?

Comment: C, C++, and C# are all different languages. What you use for one is not what you would use for the others. So which language do you want the answer for?

Comment: What language are you working in? And how is this actually related to the Windows API?

Comment: Any of the above languages is fine, I'm sorry to forget stating that I might only need pseudocodes or explained methods to do this.

Answer (score 9):

```
string myString = "This is a string that will be splitted by this and that";
string foo = myString.ToUpper();

string[] byThis = foo.Split(new string[] { "THIS" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] byThat = foo.Split(new string[] { "THAT" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string[] all = foo.Split(new string[] { "THAT", "THIS" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or you can use Regex for that

```
string[] all = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(myString, "your pattern", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. If I am not allowed to use regular expression, but only list, array, dictionary, what method could you please suggest ?

Comment: @Tokenized: you are welcome, if this answer answers you question then you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so others will know that it fixes your problem.