# C# get string from string

Tags: c#, string, get

I have this code:

> ["DATA",[],{"list":["100002788277842-2","100001011669968-2","100003141742254-2","100000874473252-2","100000100157923-2","100006537786749-2","100004300660153-2","100002922930370-2","100000627202286-2","100001649542414-2","100001687548104-2","100000616160095-2","100004018411224802-0","100001526625563-2","100002802931617-0","100002802931617-3","100000959445370","100004335731372-0","100004335731372-3","1172027782-3","1172027782-0","100001356181635-3","100001356181635-0","100001526625563-3","100001526625563-0","100005292965027-3","100005292965027-0"]}

How can i get all the numbers separatelly but without "-" and the number after it? 
For example: 100002788277842 (this is the first)

Comment: Take a look at [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That doesn't look like C# to me. Do you mean that's your text and you want the code to get the numbers? Have you tried anything?

Comment: What did not work with what you tried?

Comment: what techniques have you tried?

Comment: this all is a string and i want to get all the numbers separatelly into other strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tokenize a string with delim of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803370/tokenize-a-string-with-delim-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numbers = str.Split(new [] { '"','-' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Where(word => word.All(char.IsDigit) && word.Length > 1)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: and how can i do like: for each numbers in number listview items add the number

Comment: This site isn't an interactive tutorial.

Comment: Why the 'for each item, select it' at the end of the query? `Where` should do that already.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use regular expressions for this.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d\d+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(yourstring))
{
    var number = int.Parse(m.Value);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a regular expression as follows:

```
string s = @"[""DATA"",[],{""list"":[""100002788277842-2"",""100001011669968-2"",""100003141742254-2"",""100000874473252-2"",""100000100157923-2"",""100006537786749-2"",""100004300660153-2"",""100002922930370-2"",""100000627202286-2"",""100001649542414-2"",""100001687548104-2"",""100000616160095-2"",""100004018411224802-0"",""100001526625563-2"",""100002802931617-0"",""100002802931617-3"",""100000959445370"",""100004335731372-0"",""100004335731372-3"",""1172027782-3"",""1172027782-0"",""100001356181635-3"",""100001356181635-0"",""100001526625563-3"",""100001526625563-0"",""100005292965027-3"",""100005292965027-0""]}";

string[] array = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+(?=-)")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(_ => _.Value)
                      .ToArray();
    
/* 'array' contains:

100002788277842
100001011669968
100003141742254
100000874473252
100000100157923
100006537786749
100004300660153
100002922930370
100000627202286
100001649542414
100001687548104
100000616160095
100004018411224802
100001526625563
100002802931617
100002802931617
100004335731372
100004335731372
1172027782
1172027782
100001356181635
100001356181635
100001526625563
100001526625563
100005292965027
100005292965027

*/
```

### EDIT:

Added escaped string

Comment: but this string contains bounch of "" so i need to escape the string from "829737893718","78927498279" to \"829737893718\",\"78927498279\" how can i do that?

Comment: I added the escaped string to the answer.